# how to remove chat user from roster in other end in open fire xmpp in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, openfire

I have to remove a user issue with open `fire xmpp` .

1. I Added user_1 in DeviceA it is sending Request to user_2 DeviceB,getting added.
2. When i am removing user_2 from DeviceA, it should remove user_1 in DeviceB
   but user_1 not removing from DeviceB roster
3. I am not receiving IQ packet `subscription="remove"`

   I have received IQ packet like `subscription="to"` and `subscription="none"`

   How to resolve this Issue?

The above scenario is working as expected in the `openfire 3.6` but having problem with 4.1.

Comment: This happens when both users are online or only when 1 of them is offline at request time?

Comment: both users  are in online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Openfire 4.1 is behaving correctly according to [this defect](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-24) seen on Openfire 3.6.4 but fixed as of 3.9.2. According to [RFC-3921](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3921) Section 8.6:

> When the user removes the contact from the user's roster, the end
> state of the contact's roster is that the user is still in the
> contact's roster with a subscription state of "none"; in order to
> completely remove the roster item for the user, the contact needs to
> also send a roster removal request.

To implement what you want, you can explicitly send a remove IQ as discussed here:

- [Delete a Friend from Roster in Xmpp/Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317580/delete-a-friend-from-roster-in-xmpp-openfire)

And you can refer to the best practice here:

- https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0162.html#removal

Comment: chat history message are not getting in "fetchChatHistoryWithJID"method                  `<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="arcreq1" to="sampleJID"><error code="501" type="cancel"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>`

Comment: @Nagendar Could you please capture the stanza sent by the "fetchChatHistoryWithJID" method?

Comment: `NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement  elementWithName:@"iq"];
    NSXMLElement *list = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"list"];
    NSXMLElement *set = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"set"];
    NSXMLElement *max = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"max"]; 
    NSXMLElement *before = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"before"];
    
    [set addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"];
    [list addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"urn:xmpp:archive"];
    [list addAttributeWithName:@"with" stringValue:JID];`

Comment: @Nagendar Could you please paste the final XML text generated by the above code? That will be much easier.

Comment: `<iq type='get' id='334'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='user4@mydomain.com'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>30</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>`

Comment: i tried with this link but still having that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853071/feature-not-implemented-while-retrieving-archive-message

Comment: Yeah, the request looks fairly legit. I am not very experienced in message archiving, but I feel you do not have the message archiving support on the server side. Do you have the OpenArchive plugin installed? (As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454587/retrieving-archive-messages-using-openfire-monitoring-plugin)

Comment: @Nagendar Since this discussion is now off-topic, you might want to create another question.

Comment: thank you buddy ,we are installed monitor plug-in but its not worked as expected . I will forward this link to server side.

Answer (score 0):

think Openfire 4.1 is behaving correctly according to this defect seen on Openfire 3.6.4 but fixed as of 3.9.2. According to RFC-3921 Section 8.6:

When the user removes the contact from the user's roster, the end state of the contact's roster is that the user is still in the contact's roster with a subscription state of "none"; in order to completely remove the roster item for the user, the contact needs to also send a roster removal request.
To implement what you want, you can explicitly send a remove IQ as discussed here:

Delete a Friend from Roster in Xmpp/Openfire
And you can refer to the best practice here:

https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0162.html#removal